# How do you apply conditional formatting to a look up value which is a date from another list - e.g. red for overdue?

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

I have a list A which notes a task and the due date.

I have created a column in list B which looks up the due date in list A.

If the due date has passed, I want it to turn red to indicate that it is overdue, or if possible some sort of icon e.g. clock.

Have tried below but the date just remains green, whether overdue or not. I imagine that when the date is pulled from List A, it comes through as a string and has to be converted to a date? Not familiar with JSON so not sure how this can be achieved. Thanks.

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'red',if(@currentField <= @now + 2592000000 && @currentField > @now,'orange','green'))"
  }
}
```

Comment: The due date column in lookup column settings is selected as main lookup column or additional/extended column?